# CKEditor how to allow href="javascript:void(0)" in a widget

Tags: javascript, widget, ckeditor

I cannot find a clean solution on how to let CKEditor keep `href="javascript:void(0)"` in a link that I have placed in the template of my widget. When I save it, by calling `CKEDITOR.instances.*.getData()`, it returns `href="javascript void(0)"`.

I have tried setting `config.allowedContent = true;` & `config.linkJavaScriptLinksAllowed = true;` in config.js, but they both do not seem to do anything...

I have read [this page](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/d971319f04) where it indicates that this should be fixed, but this does not work. Any ideas?

Below the simplified plugin.js parts that are interesting. This allows for a `href` attribute in the link, but it still strips out the `:`.

```
template: 
  '<div class="container">' +
    '<a href="javascript:void(0)">' +
      '<span class="label">Label</span>' +
    '</a>' +
  '</div>',

allowedContent:
  'a[href]; div(*); span(*);',

editables: {
  Label: {
    selector: '.label',
    allowedContent: ''
    }
 }
```

CKEditor version: 4.5.9
Browser: Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bug fix](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/d971319f04) you have found in the changelog was implemented only for the Link dialog so it only works when inserting links via the plugin dialog.

As far as I understand, your case is different because you are using a link with `href="javascript:void(0)` as a part of a widget template. Not exactly sure what your template structure is and how exactly you are creating the widget, but when creating it you can use the [`editables`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-editables) property to define the elements that are allowed inside this editable part of the widget:

```
editables: {
    content: {
        selector: '.widget-content',
        allowedContent: 'p a[href]'
    }
}
```

So using [`allowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.dev/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent) you define allowed content for this part of the widget - in this case a `p` tag and a `a` tag with the `href` attribute. With such configuration `<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>` should be inserted correctly.

You can read more about allowed content rules [in the documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.dev/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules).

Comment: thanks for you post! However that does not work, the problem was not getting a href attribute in, but the javascript in the href. I have updated my answer with some code to make it clearer

Comment: @Bastiaan thanks for clarification. Can you tell me which browser are you using? The `javascript:void(0)` with the above set up seems to work fine in Chrome.

Comment: aaaahhh, after your comment that suggested it was not CKEditor, I found out that it was stripped from the $POST array by the server!! Thank you so much for this. Shall I delete this post, as it seems to make no sense now?

Comment: @Bastiaan, no problem, glad I could help. I think it is better to leave it so someone else may find it helpful:)